# JQuery .click event on a tag not triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, wai-aria

I Have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#NextFrom").click(function () {
        alert('hi');
    })
});
</script>
<form action="/Book" id="bookform" method="post">
  <a class="btn btn-lg btn-success btnNext pull-right" value="next" aria-controls="to" id="NextFrom" href="#">NEXT</a>
</form>
```

But for some reason the event is not triggered.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using the following jQuery scripts:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/vendor/jquery-1.11.4.ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have included the files **before** your script?

Comment: The script includes is in the head or at the end of the body? Maybe this is the reason. You obtain an error in your javascript console?

Comment: I have just uploaded your code to jsFiddle and it works fine there jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/sehjyn1n/ have you included all the js file?

Comment: can you show a simplified version of the structure of your html page (what's on `<head>` and before closing `</body>`)? I think there is something going on with the paths of your scripts

Comment: You have included **two** (`1.11.3` & `1.11.4`) versions of jQuery. Is that on purpose?

Comment: @D4V1D these are different libraries. One loads jQuery and the other jQuery UI.

Comment: @JcDenton86: Right, I haven't noticed the `.ui.`.

Comment: Yes, I had my jQuery inclusion after the script - dooo
BUT after moving it to the head section the aria effect of the link is not working any more - it's supposed to change tab in a tabpanel.

Comment: Maybe the question should be deleted?

Comment: @ThorOstergaard You can add your scripts right before the closing body tag (`</body>`) in correct order and of course your custom JavaScript (which uses jQuery) below the jQuery inclusion (better bellow of all your libraries so to be sure that anything you' ll use it will have been loaded first).

Answer (score 0):

semi colon was missing..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#NextFrom").click(function (event) {
      alert('hi');
   });
});
```

Comment: Someone already posted this solution, but right now he/she removed those post as the semicolon was't mandatory in js.

Answer (score -1):

I tried your code on my side, and everything seems to work. I think your problem came from the jquery inclusion, check this link to see if the jquery is indeed well included or not  :

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.fr/2009/03/check-if-jqueryjs-is-loaded.html

Comment: "*I tried it and it worked*" is not an answer to the OP's problem. Check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @JolanC I have already provided a jsFiddle of his code in the comments

Comment: @D4V1D what i meant was that the problem does not come from is code because it work for me, but from the jquery inclusion.

Comment: @JolanC: Yes but still, you're not providing a solution to the OP's problem. In that case, you shouldn't answer but comment (when you have enough rep).

Comment: @Canvas i saw it after i've posted my comment, sorry ^^

Comment: @D4V1D thanks for telling me this, i'll do this next time

Comment: @JolanC not a problem mate